# Java + ChromeDriver + Docker: CreatePlatformSocket() failed: Address family not supported by protocol (97)

Tags: java, docker, selenium-chromedriver

I have a Java application using selenium and ChromeDriver to test some applications, say, app A, B and C.

My local environment works fine both in visual and headless mode (Chrome version 66.0.3359.139 64 bits) and it takes 5 seconds to test each application.

When running headless in a jenkins docker node (Chrome version 71), app A and C logs:

> Starting ChromeDriver 2.46.628388 on port 15981
>
> Only local connections are allowed. Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
>
> [SEVERE]: CreatePlatformSocket() failed: Address
>   family not supported by protocol (97)
>
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession INFO:
>   Detected dialect: OSS

But runs all tests fine.

App B, on the other hand, logs:

> Starting ChromeDriver 2.46.628388 on port 15981
>
> Only local connections are allowed. Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
>
> [SEVERE]: CreatePlatformSocket() failed: Address
>   family not supported by protocol (97)
>
> [SEVERE]: CreatePlatformSocket() failed: Address
>   family not supported by protocol (97)
>
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession INFO:
>   Detected dialect: OSS

And "hangs" for some 15 minutes before continuing.

This is how I configure the driver:

```java
    private static WebDriver createChromeDriver() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", DRIVER_PATH);
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        if (ENABLE_HEADLESS) {
            options.addArguments("--headless");
            options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
            options.addArguments("--disable-web-security");
            options.addArguments("--no-first-run");
            options.addArguments("--no-check-default-driver");
            options.addArguments("--allow-running-insecure-content");
            options.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
            options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
            options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
            options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
            options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
            options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", singletonMap("profile.default_content_settings.geolocation", 2));
        }
        options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);

        ChromeDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        chromeDriver.manage().window().maximize();
        return chromeDriver;
    }
```

I tried just with "--headless", but I had the same problem.

Comment: Getting same error. Did you get a solution. @Saita

Comment: Any answers to this???